# pexpect - capturing stdout of a process started by a process

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, pexpect

In order to run some functions, I have a series of consoles I must recursively connect to.

- localhost: `aws ssm start-session ...` to shell into a bastion instance.
- bastion: call a shell script that starts a ruby on rails container and connects to it
- rails container: here is where I call some functions and then exit

I want to programmatically manage this, and as far as I can tell, `pexpect` is the best answer.

Expected behavior: `pexpect.spawn` a process, trigger a series of `sendline()` commands, capture all stdout from the rails container, exit.

In the aforementioned layout, stdout is not captured from the rails container.  I am running a form of the following:

```
aws_command = "aws ssm start-session ..."
p = pexpect.spawn(aws_command, encoding='utf-8')
logfile = open("logs.txt", 'w')
p.logfile = logfile
p.expect('$')
p.sendline('ls')

# ... other setup commands/env vars ...

p.sendline('this is where the command for a shell script that starts a ruby on rails container is sent')
p.expect('Loading') # this is the final line catpured from the ssm process before the rails console begins
time.sleep(30) # extra wait for good measure
p.sendline('2+2') # should see an output of 4 in the logs
time.sleep(5)
p.sendline('exit')
p.kill(0)
```

This yields the following in `logs.txt` (parts redacted):

```
Starting session with SessionId: ... # initial SSM output

sh-4.2$ # SSM shell

# the ls input and output is successfully captured here.

sh-4.2$ 'ruby on rails container shell script invoked here'

Starting console ... # output from the rails container shell script

Loading ... (Rails ...) # final output captured from the rails container shell script

2+2 # 4 not captured
exit
```

While it is clear that stdout from the rails container is not being captured, I'm not even sure if the `2+2` input from the `sendline()` is even *reaching* the rails container.  I've done a test where I've added `p.interact()` immediately after sending `2+2` (`p.interact()` gives the user immediate control over the current process).  This successfully brings me to the rails console, where 2+2 is entered and 4 is returned.  However, I cannot tell what is happening when I don't call `p.interact()` (which, in final usage, I do not want to ever call `p.interact()`).

I have also tried piping the rails container shell script command into `tee` and then catting the file after the `exit` command is sent.  However, this didn't yield any inputs or outputs (which might be a smoking gun).

Main questions:

- is pexpect capable of managing a process-within-a-process like above?
- is output not being captured, or is input not being sent to the rails container?

Curious to see if anyone else has had this issue before.  I suspect I will have to inject an intermediate python script to the `ssm` instance from which I could manage the rails container command, and then fully pipe input and output through the intermediate process to the localhost process.

Comment: you need to `expect()` something after `sendlien()`.

Comment: `expect()` is just a blocking call that waits for a particular regex before continuing, in this case we never see `4` and `except()` eventually times out and throws an exception.

Comment: please post a [repro].